# Not appending on the top left corner of grid

Tags: jquery, html, css, append, css-grid

I have a `<div class="mainbody"></div>`
with CSS of:

```
    .mainbody{  
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;
    }
```

After retrieving items from the database, I dynamically added a div inside the main body using

```
var elem = 
       "<div class='card animated fadeIn' id=" + listItemInfo.currentId+"> 
          <div class='top'>
           <span class='header'><b>"+listItemInfo.Equipment+"</b></span> 
          </div>
          <div class='main'>
             <div class='title'><span class='header2'><b></b></span>
                                <span class='date'></span>
             </div>
             <div class='itemheader'>
               <span class='item model'><b>Model</b></span>
               <span class='item status'><b>Status</b></span>
               <span class='item end'><b>End</b></span>
            </div>
          </div>";

        $(".mainbody").append(elem);
```

It's working, but the first item is added on the 1st row, 2nd column... help me fix this please.. the 1st item must be on the top left

Comment: share a complete code that we can run

Comment: Use *.prepend()* instead of *.append()*.

Comment: Thank you.. .prepend() is working perfectly